# How to move reading configuration/arguments in a separate class. Inject that class then in Main application class and use it?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am reading a few arguments in my main class in spring boot applications. Now, I want to move the logic of reading the arguments in a separate class say 'ConfigurationReader' in util package then  Inject that class(ConfigurationReader) in Main application class and use it. How can I achieve that?

Mainclass.java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = new JobConfiguration();
    jobConfiguration.setJobType(ProgramJobType.fromValue(args[0]));
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    if (!args[1].isEmpty() && args[1].length() >= 20) {
        jobConfiguration.setTriggerTime(Utility.getFormattedTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.parse(args[1].substring(0, 19), formatter)));
    }
    if(!args[2].isEmpty() && args[2].length()>=7){
        jobConfiguration.setProgramNumber(new BigInteger(args[2]));
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, I want to move this logic to read configuration in a separate class then inject that class in Main class & use it.

Comment: Be careful with your formatting. Indenting four spaces triggers formatting as code. I fixed your post this time.

Comment: And how is this related to Spring Boot? If you are using Spring you can use `@Value` to inject and convert properties directly, when using Spring Boot you can use a properties object to hold the settings.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not reading values from application.properties file. I am passing the run time arguments to me main method while running the jar

Comment: For a Spring Boot application that doesn't make any difference (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). So unless you aren't using Spring Boot re-invent the wheel, else use the framework. If they are unnamed parameters you can just pass them as properties as well while constructing the `SpringApplication`.

Comment: The code snippet is very short to actually show you're using spring boot here. The shown main method itself has nothing to do with spring boot. Usually you would have an Application class and let it extend `CommandLineRunner` to implement a method where your Spring ApplicationContext is available. Then you could simply move your code from your current main to an own class annotated with `@Component` and let it inject into the constructor of your main Application class.